# Laravel Eloquent images/pages relationship setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm moving over to Laravel and figured the best way to learn is to rebuild my own CMS in Laravel but I'm struggling with the following:

I'm using Laravel 5.4

I have five tables (with corresponding models set up):

```
images (id, type_id, item_id)
images_types (id)
images_types_templates (type_id, template_id)
pages (id, template_id)
templates (id)
```

I'm trying to set up an eloquent relationship so that I can run this in Tinker:

```
Page::with(['images'])->first()
```

And see the related images for this page(item_id) AND template_id

So far I can only retrieve items with this in my model:

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image', 'item_id');
    }
```

This does work, however it only retrieves a pages.id that matches an images.item_id

Whereas I need to check that the **images.type_id** matches the current page. This gets set from the **pages** table (**pages.template_id**, which needs to check the **images_types_templates.template_id** to see if this sort of image is allowed on this page)

I was hoping I could run Page::with(['images']) and only see images relating to this page and template_id. The **item_id** field in the **images** table could relate to any other part of the website, not just pages which is why it is **item_id** and not **page_id**

Hope that makes sense

Comment: your requirement is confusing..can you re iterate which tables to be returned with the query and in which model do you want to place this query

Comment: what does item_id refer to?  And, in your pages table, do you have an image_id column?  It seems you only have a relationship (table wise) to template_id

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

So on my Page.php model I have:

```
public function template()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Template', 'id', 'template_id');
}
```

Then on my Template.php model:

```
public function type(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ImageType::class,'images_types_templates','template_id', 'type_id');
}
```

I can then run this in tinker:

```
Page::with(['template', 'template.type'])->get()
```

And it returns this:

```
App\Page {#752
     id: 1,
     template_id: 1,
     parent_id: 0,
     slug: "home",
     title: "Home",
     subtitle: null,
     menu_title: "Home",
     content: null,
     meta_title: "Home",
     meta_description: null,
     meta_keywords: null,
     show_in_nav: 1,
     published: 1,
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     template: App\Template {#759
       id: 1,
       title: "Homepage",
       filename: "home",
       selectable: 0,
       created_at: "2018-02-09 09:17:53",
       updated_at: null,
       type: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#763
         all: [
           App\ImageType {#771
             id: 1,
             title: "Banners",
             path: "banners",
             pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#766
               template_id: 1,
               type_id: 1,
             },
           },
         ],
       },
     },
   },
```

:)